# Round millseconds timestamp to nearest 30 seconds

Tags: ruby

I have following ruby code to get current time in "milliseconds", for example: `1648059542287` which is equivalent to `Wed Mar 23 2022 18:19:02`

What I need is timestamp rounded to nearest 30 seconds, for above example, I need it rounded to `1648059540000`. Any suggestions?

```
@ctime = Time.now.to_f
(@ctime * 1000).to_i
```

Comment: `(1648059542287 / 30000) * 30000` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the time you provided,  I think this will do what you want:

1. Take your time, convert it to an integer
2. divide by floating point value 30 the number of half minutes
3. round that value and multiple by 30 to get back to the number of seconds
4. Create a new time object based on the rounded value.

```rb
input = Time.at(1648059542,287000)
Time.at((input.to_i / 30.0).round * 30)
```

Comment: The second argument to `Time.at` is the number of microseconds, i.e. you have to pass `287000`. Ruby 3.1 also allows `msec:` as a keyword argument.  Alternatively you can pass a rational number, e.g. `Time.at(Rational(1648059542287, 1000))`

Comment: @Stefan thanks,  I corrected that.  I guess in the end to_i only gives you seconds anyway.